# Autocomplete Dropdown Search Width adjustment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to design a search bar with an autocomplete dropdown like Google's. However, the dropdown does not come up as wide as the search bar

IT WORKS ON MICROSOFT EDGE BUT NOT ON GOOGLE CHROME

I have tried changing the width to auto and device-width but I see no change in autocomplete dropdown's width

.input-group-btn{
width:auto;

}

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
body{
 background:#202a3f;
}
.container{
 margin-top:200px;
}
.glyphicon-search{
 font-size:20px;
}

.btn-default{
 background: orange;
 width:100px;
 padding:12.5px;
}

.form-control{
 padding:25px;
 font-size:20px;
 
}

.input-group-btn{
width:auto;


}

}
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar" >
  <a href="#home" >Home</a>
  <a href="#favorites">Favorites</a>
  <div class = "dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Genre
  <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"></i>
 </button>
 <div class ="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Drama</a>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
  <div class = "input-group">
   <input type="text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
   <div class ="input-group-btn ">
   <button  type="submit" class = "btn btn-default">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
   </div>
   </div>
 </form>
  </div>



</body>


</html>
```

When I keep the width auto or device-width, the drop down is really small, however, if the width is some huge actual number like 1000px or 30000px, whole search bar shrinks in width and then the dropdown is as wide as the search bar.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How much i understand you problem is your want to increase the width of search input box and the autocomplete comes under 100% as with provided to your search input box.
first of all include the jquery.min.js for remove the jquery error showing in your console.
after that do some changes which i done in your css and html for resolve the issue.

```css
body{
  background:#202a3f;
}

.form {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom-layout{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.custom-layout button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container{
  margin-top:200px;
}

.glyphicon-search{
  font-size:20px;
}

.btn-default{
  background: orange;
  width:100px;
  padding:12.5px;
}

.form-control {
  padding:25px;
  font-size:20px;
}

.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" >
   <a href="#home" >Home</a>
   <a href="#favorites">Favorites</a>
   <div class = "dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Genre
      <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class ="dropdown-content">
         <a href="#">Drama</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <form action="/action_page.php" class="form">
      <div class = "input-group custom-layout">
         <input type="text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
         <div class ="input-group-btn">
            <button  type="submit" class = "btn btn-default">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It still doesnt work. I still get the same kind of output as I used to. I forgot to mention that the output doesnt work on Chrome but it does on Microsoft Edge